# How can I use several computers to speed up rendering?

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to set up and use a number of mac minis to speed up rendering, if yes how do I set it up? I am working from a Mac Pro and have 5 additional Mac minis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Netrender](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:ZH/2.6/Manual/Render/Performance/Netrender)  for that.

It's a bit tricky to set it up and get it working.I managed to get it working at one point, but not lately.

Another option is to open the blend file on each computer and render it with the same settings, BUT with fewer passes and different seeds. You can then manually merge the layers in an image editor.

Answer (score 0):

Netrender is an option, but it's exceedingly tricky. Described here is a much better option.

### Modifying the Blendfile

Always make adjustments 4 and 6 from [this page](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/). Make the others as possible. I've found that by making these adjustments, you can reduce the render samples by a good bit and still get a crystal clear image.

Also change the tile size to 16x16 for CPU (what a mac uses) as per [this other page](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/). Consider the other modifications if they fit.

### Rendering

Open the .blend file on all of the computers. In a 120 frame animation with 6 computers, have computer 1 render frames 1-20, computer 2 render 21-40, and so on and so forth. When finished, stitch all the video files together using Blender's built in [Video Sequence Editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/editors/sequencer/index.html).